# How do I check if the fifth bit of a flag value is 0 or 1 using sql query?

Tags: mysql, sql, flags

Consider I have a column called flag in my db that is from 8 bit binary number with 8 separate flags.How do I find the fifth flag if it is 1 or 0 ? And how do I update the values in that 5th bit if I want?

Comment: can you please provide table structure and expected output that will help to understand the question in better way.

Answer (score 2):

You could use  a  bitwise operatore  `&` (and) for a proper mask

```
SELECT your_number & 1 
from dual
```

if return  1 (true) then the last bit is 1 else is 0

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/bit-functions.html